# Why does the_content not work like others for a set post id?

Tags: wp-query, loop

Here's something odd, I want to print out a certain post on any page request, if you have a constant $idnumber of your favorite page/message, then add:

```
$GLOBALS['post'] = get_post( $idnumber );
```

`the_title();` echos that specific page's title,

`get_permalink();` looks ok too,

but `the_content()` actually ignores the post set, and just prints whatever page was requested, again.

Comment: Can you please share your entire piece of code?

Comment: So you want to display the post based on id?

Answer (score 2):

There are many globals that are being set in a loop, not only `$post`, and you need to set all of them to get exactly the same behavior. To get this it is not enough to set `$post` but you also need to use [setup_postdata](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/setup_postdata/)

Answer (score 0):

Well, from my side is better to use `WP_query()` for this and define all in variables. Reason for that is because you can define sparate loops foreah WP_query. Also you need to clean all prevous query when you get info.

Answer (score -2):

Really the_content filter is most of what you need to do to be like the_content, but not require all those other variables the_content() expects.

Comment: So is this not proper? You can see that the_content() just grabs content and runs `$content = apply_filters( 'the_content', $content );
 $content = str_replace( ']]>', ']]&gt;', $content );
 echo $content;`